# Intel 12th Gen only efficient core were used for the computation

Tags: python-3.x, windows, parallel-processing, intel, scheduling

Using an Intel 12th gen laptop on Windows 11 with parallelization for a computational task.

In the first run both the power cores and the efficient cores were activated, with the power core running at 100% and the efficient core at 80%.

After a while the utilization of the efficient core slowly went up to 100%. But on the second run, the power cores were never used and only the efficient cores were at 100%.

It's not a displacement mistake from the windows 11 because the computer temperature cooled and the fan stopped buzzering. But strangely with the power core at rest the computer still became stuck and froze.

The third run both the power cores and the efficient cores were actived.

How was this possible and how to tell python to use all the cores?

Comment: Doubtful that it's something you could tell *Python*; it's Windows that decides which core should run any given task.  More likely a question for https://superuser.com/, except possibly for using Python functions to make system calls that force the affinity mask so some of your tasks run on a set of cores that only includes P-cores.   But if your computer locked up so you had to reboot it, that sounds like a problem; that should obviously never happen with bug-free software (and hardware).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thought the python could specify how many cores to be used. Reboot the program could work but it's not guaranteed. It's significantly faster and more efficient in the power usage(the room won't get 10 degrees hotter) once it worked.